# Is there an IBM Iseries/DB2 equivalent to SQL Profiler?

Tags: sql, profiling, db2, ibm-midrange

Subject says it all. Looking to capture sql submitted to DB2.

Comment: Where does the SQL come from?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Iseries SQL Exit Points which will allow you to log any submitted SQL.  The only problem is you will have to write your own programs to do the logging:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikodbcexitprog.htm

Comment: There are additional potential problems. First is system security. Writing network exit programs without a full understanding of behavior is risky to the system. Exit programs can be able to override system security settings. Returning an incorrect 'Accept/Reject' flag for a given transaction can be trouble. Other potential problems can be listed, but it might be avoided by using the QIBM_QDB_OPEN exit point and staying a step away from the network. SQL can be accessed by the exit program by calling QUSRJOBI format JOBI0900. It also uses 'Accept/Reject', but at a different layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java support enabled, you can use SQL PL Profiler.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0406rielau/index.html

Comment: It appears that the OP is running on an iSeries – this article only applies to DB2 running on Linux/UNIX/Windows.

Answer (score 0):

i use the DB2 Command Center with a graphical view of the generated tree

Comment: Can you give me more info? Also, where can I get it?

Comment: Command Center can show you the explain plan for a particular query, but it will not capture SQL executing in the engine.

Comment: that is only partly tru. You can launch an activity monitor with lots of information. But it is very ugly (Java-slow)

Answer (score 0):

In iSeries Navigator, there is SQL Performance Monitor. I haven't ever been able to figure it out, but it might be what you are looking for.

[image: screen shot of iSeries Navigator]

Comment: Starting a general performance monitor over all tables is probably a bad idea, especially over a production system.  You may have better luck looking at the plan cache instead (don't really know, I'm not a DBA).  I have run into situations where 'general' performance monitors 'disallow' other monitors to be started, because of the setup (logging to locked-down library, couldn't request access over a file because of that).