# DB2 Where are profile tool like SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: db2, profiler

I'm using DB2 9.5. Is there exists tool like SQL Server Profiler? 
I want to view all executing SQL queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an IBM Iseries/DB2 equivalent to SQL Profiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257667/is-there-an-ibm-iseries-db2-equivalent-to-sql-profiler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To watch all executed queries you can create an event monitor. Please see [CREATE EVENT MONITOR statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000915.html) for statements.

Answer (score 2):

Finally have found a nice small and light-weight and freeware tool: **db2mon**.
http://www.db2mon.com/

Comment: Anyone else getting a "The program can't start because DB2APP.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.?

Comment: You have to install DB2 Control Center with these libs. Or tryin to place required dll-s near the db2mon.